# How to make PostgreSQL react on bad execution plans and update its statistics?

Tags: postgresql

When the statistics are outdated, it is obvious that the execution plan will be sub-optimal. AFAIK, nothing will prevent PG to repeat the same bad-planned executions again and again unless one triggers a manual ANALYZE or autovacuum kicks in.

But wouldn't it be possible for PG to figure out, maybe by leveraging [auto_explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html), that the real execution dramatically negatively differs from the planner expectations and trigger a ANALYZE? (even though the autovacuum thresholds are not triggered yet)

Comment: Autovacuum, if properly configured, will guarantee that you never have outdated statistics. There is no magical tuning facility.

Comment: So the key is proper Autovacuum configuration ;)

Comment: Yes. And there is also no magic that automatically does that.